# ubuntu 20.04 Error - LogicException While trying command-sudo php artisan |

Tags: php, database, ubuntu, exception, laravel-artisan

After trying all this in ubuntu 20.04

```
/var/www/snipe-it$ sudo php artisan route:clear                                 Route cache cleared!
/var/www/snipe-it$ sudo php artisan config:clear                                Configuration cache cleared!
/var/www/snipe-it$ sudo php artisan route:clear
Route cache cleared!
/var/www/snipe-it$ sudo php artisan cache:clear                                 Application cache cleared!
/var/www/snipe-it$ sudo php artisan optimize                                    Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
Route cache cleared!

Getting Error-

LogicException While trying command-sudo php artisan | Getting the Error-   Unable to prepare route [api/v1/consumables/view/{id}/users] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [api.consumables.showUsers].
 at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php:218
    214▕             $route->name($name = $this->generateRouteName());
    215▕
    216▕             $this->add($route);
    217▕         } elseif (! is_null($symfonyRoutes->get($name))) {
  ➜ 218▕             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$route->uri}] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [{$name}].");
    219▕         }
    220▕
    221▕         $symfonyRoutes->add($route->getName(), $route->toSymfonyRoute());
    222▕

      +30 vendor frames
  31  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: `Another route has already been assigned name [api.consumables.showUsers]` - Have you defined two different routes with the same name? A copy/paste mishap perhaps?

Comment: @M.Eriksson - How could I know? I am doing this installation(snipe-it) first time.

Comment: _"How could I know?"_ - Check your code where you have defined routes and see if anyone has been assigned that same name. If you don't know how Laravel's routing works, check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing. If you haven't written it yourself, or you've downloaded/gotten it from someone, ask them about it. All we can see is the error which says that there already is a route with that name. We don't know anything else about the application

Comment: can we do this together on screen sharing can i share my anydesk id, let me know a suitable time to connect i am in india...if you can help me out personally, it would be highly appreciated Mr. Eriksson :)

Comment: Sorry, that's not how this site works. Read Laravel's documentation, look at a bunch of guides/tutorials and learn how it works. There are tons of tutorials for Laravel. It's a part of being a developer. If you don't want to/can't do it, you need to hire a developer. We're here to help and answers questions here on SO. If we answer questions off-site, then the questions would stay unanswered, and others wouldn't be able to benefit from them.